# How to make a Lex/Yacc parser which accepts navigation keys?

Tags: yacc, lex

I've created a simple parser using Lex/Yacc.

My problem is, when I run this parser and type text into the console, each time I press the left arrow key, the cursor doesn't move to the left as expected, instead I get this strange group of characters: "^[[D"

Do you have any idea how to make the left arrow key works as expected?

Thank you.

Comment: This has nothing to do with either lex or yacc. Try making a simple program that simply reads from stdin what it can and prints everything it reads to stdout, and you'll see the same behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, hvd. It seems that I have to rely on some readline library functions to implement this feature. Do you have any comment about this approach?

Comment: There are several libraries that can do the job for you, and readline is indeed one of them, but I don't know enough about the alternatives to say which is probably the most suitable for you. (And for such comparisons of libraries, SO is not a good place.)

Comment: You should use readline (or something similar) if you want line-editing facilities.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is happening: The arrow key generates a sequence of characters, not  single character. THey are ancient VT100 codes.  The three character sequence [A is up, [B is down, [C is right, and [D is left.

Some applications (like KSHELL) handle these escape sequences. When you do a left arrow, they know to send an escape sequence back to the terminal/terminal window that move the cursor left and they internally move the position of the insert location.

Such applications also do single character input.

If you just do plain vanilla C/C++ or other high level language read operations, you do not have the functionality available to you. Your generic C/C++ input does not return data to you charater-by-character. Instead, it buffers the data until you type . In other words, this is not a YACC/LEX problem but rather a general input programming problem.

If you want editing functionality, you need to us something that will perform character level input and process the escape sequences.

As the comments say, you need to use some library that will handle this for you.

Comment: The normal way to handle these things on Linux/UNIX systems is [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/)